# GTFS Data Feed Server

Tags: android, mysql, sql, sql-server, gtfs

I am taking a drive into GTFS (and only a couple months into learning Android coding).  I signed up as a Developer for my transit system and received a key for their GTFS data download.

However, they require that you download the GTFS data to your own servers rather than pointing your Android App directly to their servers to get the feed.  Basically, I need to accomplish the below.

**Their Servers** ---Data---> **My Server** ---Data---> **My App**

My app will have all the tools to read/manipulate the data so the My Server part should do nothing to change the data.

I've looked into services like Amazon Web Services which has a free tier but not sure if that is what I need.  Also, if it is what I need, then unsure of how to tell it to get/store the data from the transit system's servers.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: What you are looking for is a tutorial for building a web service. Both data intake to your sql/nosql database in the cloud as well as delivery to your own app. Unfortunately asking for such is off-topic, but tutorials should be found via using a search engine. Good luck.

Comment: great thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

One of the easiest ways to get started, if you want to host your own server, is to use [node-gtfs](https://github.com/brendannee/node-gtfs). However it is not the only way.

The shortest learning curve would be to use one of the two services that host transit data and provide APIs that you can use to build your own app:

- [Transitland](https://transit.land/)
- [TransitFeeds.com](http://transitfeeds.com/)

There are also a number of other libraries/tools/servers in other programming languages (depending on what you are comfortable with and what your goals are). [OneBusAway](http://onebusaway.org/) is probably the most robust but unlikely to run on the AWS free tier. A good list of the others can be found [here](https://github.com/luqmaan/awesome-transit#gtfs-libraries).